# How to install Ubuntu on ARMv7 hardware?

Tags: system-installation, arm

I was wondering how can I install normal Ubuntu working version on a device that has an ARMv7 processor?

Comment: You've tagged this question with `android`, which is not really related to Ubuntu on ARM.  Is there a particular device you're talking about here?

Comment: James is right, please remove Android from the headline and tags and add information about the hardware to be used. If you are new to this you might first want to do some experiments with pandaboard. The generic way is to create one or two partitions on the flash memory (two in case of pandaboard - there it is an SD card, which makes it easy). For booting, use the u-boot bootloader and the kernel provided with the downloaded ubuntu-arm-version. There is also a file where you configure kernel boot args. However - way more information is necessary to help you!!!

Comment: Have you read https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM ?

Answer (score 5):

Do you mean ARM7 or ARMv7?

If the former, I don't believe you can - not with Ubuntu. Other distros might though. Debian certainly supports ARM11, and maybe older. Gentoo might also, and if not you can probably rebuild it so most of the software works, assuming the kernel is OK. I can't just put my finger on any positive statement from any of them though.

Otherwise, the current Ubuntu/Linaro ARM release is for ARMv7 processors only (i.e. Cortex-A series). The best starting point is probably http://www.linaro.org.

Comment: Given that the OP originally mentioned Android, and that it's probably not well known that there's such a distinction, I've corrected the question to ARMv7.