# Ubuntu on ARM laptop

Tags: lenovo, arm

Is there any version of Ubuntu suitable for Lenovo Yoga 11, ARM based version?

There are many versions of Ubuntu, and I don't know which is the best in terms of compatibility, performance and hardware support for this device.

Answer (score 0):

If by version you mean architecture, then you should get the armhf version. All arm processors above v7 (which i only imagine you have) work with that.

Comment: Please improve your answer with steps required to obtain the said armhf version and installation procedure

Answer (score 0):

The only officially supported ARM platform at the moment appears to be [ARM64 for servers](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/server/arm). That's where you land when you follow the information in the [arm](/questions/tagged/arm) tag of your question. You could try to install the desktop package or a particular desktop and hope that it works but it's not recommended. It probably won't work with your platform since Yoga 11 is a rather generic description to derive the ARM architecture and instruction set from to give a precise answer. However there have been instructions how build a [rootfs for ARM](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RootfsFromScratch) to install it on computers and Chrouton is a prominent user of Ubuntu's arm packages but the best advice here is probably to not start this endeavour if you want a quick and reliable solution.

I there is a very similar question which is a few years older, just that Ubuntu now promotes images for ARM servers on the official page and that Ubuntu Core has been released, little progress on the desktop side though as it seems:   [How to install Ubuntu on ARMv7 hardware?](https://askubuntu.com/q/83975/40581)